# how to transfer matlab code to simulink matlab function

Tags: matlab, video, image-processing, simulink

i am looking forward to get a support to solve my issue regarding transferring matlab code to a simulink matlab function and i need a help as soon as possible.

the matlab code is :

```
%a = imaqhwinfo;
%[camera_name, camera_id, format] = getCameraInfo(a);


% Capture the video frames using the videoinput function
% You have to replace the resolution & your installed adaptor name.
vid = videoinput('winvideo',1);

% Set the properties of the video object
set(vid, 'FramesPerTrigger', Inf);
set(vid, 'ReturnedColorspace', 'rgb')
vid.FrameGrabInterval = 5;

%start the video aquisition here
start(vid)

% Set a loop that stop after 100 frames of aquisition
while(vid.FramesAcquired<=100)

    % Get the snapshot of the current frame
    data = getsnapshot(vid);

    % Now to track red objects in real time
    % we have to subtract the red component 
    % from the grayscale image to extract the red components in the image.
    diff_im = imsubtract(data(:,:,1), rgb2gray(data));
    %Use a median filter to filter out noise
    diff_im = medfilt2(diff_im, [3 3]);
    % Convert the resulting grayscale image into a binary image.
    diff_im = im2bw(diff_im,0.18);

    % Remove all those pixels less than 300px
    diff_im = bwareaopen(diff_im,300);

    % Label all the connected components in the image.
    bw = bwlabel(diff_im, 8);

    % Here we do the image blob analysis.
    % We get a set of properties for each labeled region.
    stats = regionprops(bw, 'BoundingBox', 'Centroid');

    % Display the image
    imshow(data)

    hold on

    %This is a loop to bound the red objects in a rectangular box.
    for object = 1:length(stats)
        bb = stats(object).BoundingBox;
        bc = stats(object).Centroid;
        rectangle('Position',bb,'EdgeColor','r','LineWidth',2)
        plot(bc(1),bc(2), '-m+')
        a=text(bc(1)+15,bc(2), strcat('X: ', num2str(round(bc(1))), '    Y: ', num2str(round(bc(2)))));
        set(a, 'FontName', 'Arial', 'FontWeight', 'bold', 'FontSize', 12, 'Color', 'yellow');
    end

    hold off
end
% Both the loops end here.

% Stop the video aquisition.
stop(vid);

% Flush all the image data stored in the memory buffer.
flushdata(vid);

% Clear all variables
clear all
sprintf('%s','That was all about Image tracking, Guess that was pretty easy :) ')
```

when i transfer it to simulink i got the below error:

**The 'videoinput' class does not support code generation.**

**Function 'videoinput' (#24.234.244), line 8, column 7:
"videoinput"
Launch diagnostic report.**

waiting for immediate respond for you...

regards

Comment: The error is quite obvious.  The `videoinput` class does not support code generation.  This means that you can't use `videoinput` in Simulink when you want to try and create the Simulink block version.  My suggestion would be to perhaps pre-record the video from your webcam, then use the `VideoReader` class to read in the frames first.  I believe `VideoReader` supports code generation.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned in the comments, you can't use the `videoinput` function in Simulink because it does not support code generation. Instead, use the [From Video Device](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/imaq/fromvideodevice.html) block. You should be able to put the actual image processing algorithm into a MATLAB Function block, with a few minor tweaks.

Comment: Nice!  Didn't know about this one.  +1 from me.